# Imprimir un arbol binario de busqueda por nivel

Tags: python, imprimir, python-3.9, tree

El arbol que tengo, debo imprimir sus recorridos en preorden, inorden, postorden y luego los valores del arbol por nivel.

Entonces ya tengo los recorridos y la funcion para busqueda con funciones recursivas, solo me falta lograr la impresion por niveles, ya que no consigo que imprima de la forma que necesito, ya que o me repite el valor o solo imprime el lado izquierdo...Agradeceria mucho la ayuda con esta ultima parte

En este caso la impresion deberia quedar asi:

50

30 70

20 40 60 80

Pero no consigo lograrlo

Aqui esta la parte del codigo en donde esta el nodo y la funcion de insertar y los datos:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key):
            self.left = None
            self.right = None
            self.val = key 
    
    def insert(root, key):
        if root is None:
            return Node(key)
        else:
            if root.val == key:
                return root
            elif root.val < key:
                root.right = insert(root.right, key)
            else:
                root.left = insert(root.left, key)
        return root
    
r = Node(50)
r = insert(r, 30)
r = insert(r, 20)
r = insert(r, 40)
r = insert(r, 70)
r = insert(r, 60)
r = insert(r, 80)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay que cambiar de estrategia para que visite los nodos por niveles, en vez de recorrerlos por ramas.

Por ejemplo:

```py
def print_nodes(nodes):

    if len(nodes) == 0:
        return

    for node in nodes:
        if node is not None:
            print(node.value, end="")
    print()

    children = []
    for node in nodes:
        if node is not None:
            children.append(node)

    print_nodes(children)
```

De un modo más compacto:

```py
def print_nodes(nodes):

    if not nodes:
        return

    values = [node.value for node in nodes if node.value is not None]
    print(" ".join(values))

    children = sum(([r.left,r.right] for r in nodes if r is not None), [])
    children = [node for node in children if node is not None]

    print_nodes(children)
```